# where can i find a link to download Java Card Development Kit v2.2.2?

Tags: javacard

I am trying to download the Java Card Development Kit v2.2.2 , it is not available in oracle web site , can someone help me to get a download link ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link.This might help you to download.

http://caydi31raou.chytrak.cz/websites--blogs/java-card-development-kit-v222.html

**Edited**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html

1.You can use the standard development IDE such as Eclipse for Java developer or Netbeans.

2.Download the JavaCard Kit 2.1.1 from Sun/Oracle website here. This includes the library (JAR file) and EXPort files.

3.Create your project on Eclipse. Remove the standard JRE library and put the JAR files from JCDK here.

4.The conversion to .class files are done by javac.

5.To compile class to CAP file, you need to configure ANT build file which refer to JAR and EXP of the JCDK.

You can check the following link for sample of the ANT xml

Comment: which OS your using ?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 (64 bits)

Comment: I posted the new link check it and follow that steps.

Comment: then mark it as correct answer,it might help others too.